# I can't target an SVG path ID when I click on a specific US State on a map with raphael.js, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, svg

The goal I'm trying to achieve is when I click on a specific U.S. State on an SVG MAP, I want it to update the src attribute value in an iframe to load the specific U.S. state on google map.

when I try to run this jQuery code, it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('path#0').on("click", function() {
   $('#mapRedirect').attr('src',paths[0].url);
  });
});
```

When I run this code, it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    $('#mapRedirect').attr('src',paths[0].url);
  });
});
```

The path element I'm trying to target with it's path ID:

```
<path fill="#ff0000" stroke="#000000" d="M631.30647,460.41572L629.81587,446.09422L627.06763,427.34158L627.22929,413.27709L628.03759,382.23824L627.87593,365.58718L628.04102,359.16812L672.5255,355.54867L672.3777,357.73109L672.53936,359.83269L673.18601,363.22756L676.58089,371.14893L679.00579,381.01024L680.46074,387.15335L682.07734,392.00317L683.5323,398.95458L685.63388,405.25934L688.22045,408.65423L688.70543,412.04909L690.64537,412.8574L690.80703,414.95899L689.02875,419.80881L688.54377,423.04203L688.38211,424.98195L689.99873,429.3468L690.32205,434.68159L689.51373,437.10651L690.16039,437.91481L691.61533,438.72311L691.94347,441.61193L686.34581,441.25838L679.55606,441.90503L654.01366,444.81491L643.6021,446.22168L643.38072,449.09908L645.15899,450.87735L647.74556,452.81727L648.32642,460.75271L642.78436,463.32561L640.03614,463.00229L642.78436,461.06236L642.78436,460.0924L639.71282,454.11096L637.44957,453.46432L635.99462,457.82915L634.70134,460.57738L634.0547,460.41572L631.30647,460.41572Z" stroke-width="0" opacity="0" id="0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></path>
```

Comment: I don't think most browsers will like an id starting with a digit (I think this may have changed in later specs). If changing it to an a-z character doesn't help, I would post a jsfiddle so people can inspect whats going on. This may also be useful https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: I do have a link to the website via GitHub: https://jsantana2418.github.io/client-SteveArias-HandBall-WebSite/ I wasn't sure if those would be easier to play with the web console than trying to get it all inside of jsfiddle, let me know if its a better approach to dump it into jsfiddle for review. Thanks

Comment: I tried a targeting a different element node and no matter how specific the selector is on the click event, it either targets the DOM or Window, console.log(this) reveals this information to me. So, what I would like to know is there a way to force a click event to specifically select and retrieve a nested element node as such $('#svggroup svg text tspan').text(); let's say it return with a value of "AL" for Alabama then I could run my For Loop to iterate over my Array to match an IF condition and then run my code.